# PG + extconf failed, exit code 1 in Linux

Tags: linux, postgresql, centos, rubygems

I am getting error in installing PG in Linux (CentOS) System.

> gem install pg

Then I'm getting following error

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/pg-0.18.4/ext
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160831-5454-1endyls.rb extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /usr/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --enable-windows-cross
    --disable-windows-cross
    --with-pg-config
    --without-pg-config
    --with-pg_config
    --without-pg_config
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/pg-0.18.4/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/pg-0.18.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/pg-0.18.4/gem_make.out
```

and for solution I try many things and installed required packages but still getting same error. you can see my logs for postgres*

After run

> yum list postgres*

```
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
24 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Installed Packages
postgresql92.x86_64                                                                   9.2.15-1.57.amzn1                                                        @amzn-main  
postgresql92-contrib.x86_64                                                           9.2.15-1.57.amzn1                                                        @amzn-main  
postgresql92-devel.x86_64                                                             9.2.15-1.57.amzn1                                                        @amzn-main  
postgresql92-libs.x86_64                                                              9.2.15-1.57.amzn1                                                        @amzn-main  
postgresql92-server.x86_64                                                            9.2.15-1.57.amzn1                                                        @amzn-main  
postgresql92-server-compat.x86_64                                                     9.2.15-1.57.amzn1                                                        @amzn-main  
postgresql93.x86_64                                                                   9.3.11-1.61.amzn1                                                        @amzn-main  
postgresql93-contrib.x86_64                                                           9.3.11-1.61.amzn1                                                        @amzn-main  
postgresql93-devel.x86_64                                                             9.3.11-1.61.amzn1                                                        @amzn-main  
postgresql93-libs.x86_64                                                              9.3.11-1.61.amzn1                                                        @amzn-main  
postgresql93-server.x86_64                                                            9.3.11-1.61.amzn1                                                        @amzn-main  
postgresql94.x86_64                                                                   9.4.6-1.66.amzn1                                                         @amzn-main  
postgresql94-libs.x86_64                                                              9.4.6-1.66.amzn1                                                         @amzn-main  
Available Packages
postgresql-jdbc.noarch                                                                8.4.701-8.11.amzn1                                                       amzn-main   
postgresql-jdbc-javadoc.noarch                                                        9.4.1208-1.rhel6                                                         pgdg92      
postgresql-odbc.x86_64                                                                08.04.0200-1.6.amzn1                                                     amzn-main   
postgresql8.x86_64                                                                    8.4.20-5.52.amzn1                                                        amzn-updates
postgresql8-contrib.x86_64                                                            8.4.20-5.52.amzn1                                                        amzn-updates
postgresql8-devel.x86_64                                                              8.4.20-5.52.amzn1                                                        amzn-updates
postgresql8-docs.x86_64                                                               8.4.20-5.52.amzn1                                                        amzn-updates
postgresql8-libs.i686                                                                 8.4.20-5.52.amzn1                                                        amzn-updates
postgresql8-libs.x86_64                                                               8.4.20-5.52.amzn1                                                        amzn-updates
postgresql8-plperl.x86_64                                                             8.4.20-5.52.amzn1                                                        amzn-updates
postgresql8-plpython.x86_64                                                           8.4.20-5.52.amzn1                                                        amzn-updates
postgresql8-pltcl.x86_64                                                              8.4.20-5.52.amzn1                                                        amzn-updates
postgresql8-server.x86_64                                                             8.4.20-5.52.amzn1                                                        amzn-updates
postgresql8-test.x86_64                                                               8.4.20-5.52.amzn1                                                        amzn-updates
postgresql92-debuginfo.x86_64                                                         9.2.18-1PGDG.rhel6                                                       pgdg92      
postgresql92-docs.x86_64                                                              9.2.15-1.57.amzn1                                                        amzn-main   
postgresql92-libs.i686                                                                9.2.15-1.57.amzn1                                                        amzn-main   
postgresql92-odbc.x86_64                                                              09.05.0400-1PGDG.rhel6                                                   pgdg92      
postgresql92-plperl.x86_64                                                            9.2.15-1.57.amzn1                                                        amzn-main   
postgresql92-plpython.x86_64                                                          9.2.18-1PGDG.rhel6                                                       pgdg92      
postgresql92-plpython26.x86_64                                                        9.2.15-1.57.amzn1                                                        amzn-main   
postgresql92-plpython27.x86_64                                                        9.2.15-1.57.amzn1                                                        amzn-main   
postgresql92-pltcl.x86_64                                                             9.2.15-1.57.amzn1                                                        amzn-main   
postgresql92-python.x86_64                                                            4.2-1PGDG.rhel6                                                          pgdg92      
postgresql92-python-debuginfo.x86_64                                                  4.2-1PGDG.rhel6                                                          pgdg92      
postgresql92-tcl.x86_64                                                               2.1.1-1.rhel6                                                            pgdg92      
postgresql92-tcl-debuginfo.x86_64                                                     2.1.1-1.rhel6                                                            pgdg92      
postgresql92-test.x86_64                                                              9.2.15-1.57.amzn1                                                        amzn-main   
postgresql93-docs.x86_64                                                              9.3.11-1.61.amzn1                                                        amzn-main   
postgresql93-libs.i686                                                                9.3.11-1.61.amzn1                                                        amzn-main   
postgresql93-plperl.x86_64                                                            9.3.11-1.61.amzn1                                                        amzn-main   
postgresql93-plpython26.x86_64                                                        9.3.11-1.61.amzn1                                                        amzn-main   
postgresql93-plpython27.x86_64                                                        9.3.11-1.61.amzn1                                                        amzn-main   
postgresql93-pltcl.x86_64                                                             9.3.11-1.61.amzn1                                                        amzn-main   
postgresql93-test.x86_64                                                              9.3.11-1.61.amzn1                                                        amzn-main   
postgresql94-contrib.x86_64                                                           9.4.6-1.66.amzn1                                                         amzn-main   
postgresql94-devel.x86_64                                                             9.4.6-1.66.amzn1                                                         amzn-main   
postgresql94-docs.x86_64                                                              9.4.6-1.66.amzn1                                                         amzn-main   
postgresql94-libs.i686                                                                9.4.6-1.66.amzn1                                                         amzn-main   
postgresql94-plperl.x86_64                                                            9.4.6-1.66.amzn1                                                         amzn-main   
postgresql94-plpython26.x86_64                                                        9.4.6-1.66.amzn1                                                         amzn-main   
postgresql94-plpython27.x86_64                                                        9.4.6-1.66.amzn1                                                         amzn-main   
postgresql94-server.x86_64                                                            9.4.6-1.66.amzn1                                                         amzn-main   
postgresql94-test.x86_64                                                              9.4.6-1.66.amzn1                                                         amzn-main   
postgresql_autodoc.noarch                                                             1.41-1.rhel6                                                             pgdg92
```

Unable to install pg. Please help me.

I installed

> ```
> yum install postgresql92-server
> ```

```
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-main/latest                                                                                                                                    | 2.1 kB     00:00     
amzn-updates/latest                                                                                                                                 | 2.3 kB     00:00     
24 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Package postgresql92-server-9.2.15-1.57.amzn1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems you have to install postgres header files and libraries.
as your system is RHEL try this.

```
yum install postgresql-devel
```

if you are using postgres 9.4 then,

```
yum install postgresql94-devel
```

then rerun gem install pg 'version'