# error while trying to create a new app with postgresql (rails new myapp -d postgresql)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

[screenshot of bash terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaAlZ.png)

I tried "bundle install" which gives the error "Could not locate Gemfile"

Am following this guide https://gorails.com/setup/windows/10

I tried doing the same thing in /mnt/c, but get the same error

Tried bundle install in the project directory, got this error: [image: screenshot]

Tried running "gem install pg -v '1.1.4' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'", got this error[image: screenshot]

solved with the command

> sudo apt install postgresql-contrib libpq-dev

Comment: Have you tried `bundle install`  from project directory. I mean after moving in to project directory?

Comment: tried doing that and got an error, updated post

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39251264/pg-extconf-failed-exit-code-1-in-linux and if you are using ubuntu https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116015/how-to-install-postgresqls-pg-gem-on-ubuntu